# Internal handling of IV in AES_GCM_256, for multiple encryption calls on same plaintext

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I am trying to understand the working of OpenSSL's EVP_EncryptUpdate function, specifically why does it return different cipher-text for same plaintext, key and IV (initially provided), over multiple calls. As far as I understand, the IV should be changed after each call, and the function takes care of the IV internally. The Question is how exactly is the IV handled internally? Trying to fetch the IV returns the same IV as the one the context is initialised with.

```
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

void print_array(char *title, unsigned char *buff, int len)
{
    printf("%s:\n", title);
    for(int i = 0; i<len; ++i)
        printf("%02x ", buff[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void handleErrors()
{
    printf("Error in encryption/decryption\n");
}

void encrypt_EVP_aes_256_gcm_init(EVP_CIPHER_CTX **ctx, unsigned char *key, unsigned char *iv)
{
    if(!(*ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new()))
        handleErrors();
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptInit_ex(*ctx, EVP_aes_256_gcm(), NULL, key, iv))
        handleErrors();
}

void encrypt(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, unsigned char *plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char *ciphertext, int *ciphertext_len)
{
    int len;
    if(1 != EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx, ciphertext, &len, plaintext, plaintext_len))
        handleErrors();
    *ciphertext_len = len;
}

void test(const unsigned char* key, const unsigned char* iv, const unsigned char *data, int iters)
{
    unsigned char enc_data[32];

    int32_t cipherLength;
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *encrypt_ctx;
    encrypt_EVP_aes_256_gcm_init(&encrypt_ctx, key, iv);

    for(int i = 0; i<iters; ++i)
    {
        print_array("iv", EVP_CIPHER_CTX_iv(encrypt_ctx), 12);    
    
        encrypt(encrypt_ctx, data, 32, enc_data, &cipherLength);

        print_array("enc data", enc_data, cipherLength);
    }
}

int main()
{
    const unsigned char* key =             "\x3c\x57\x5e\x25\x5f\x43\x41\x69\x3d\x5e\x48\x29\x72\x54\x27\x55\x3e\x29\x28\x65\x31\x34\x4a\x3e\x52\x2f\x7c\x6a\x7b\x25\x78\x52";
    const unsigned char* iv = "\x75\x71\x71\x55\x36\x33\x59\x52\x2c\x22\x74\x7d\x6f\x36\x6d\x2e";
    const unsigned char data[32] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";

    test(key, iv, data, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried outputting the IV, but it does not seem to display the running IV. I only get back the supplied IV.

Comment: The IV is handled internally to algorithm implementation, and intermediate internal states are not something the caller needs to be concerned with. In any event, you're not using the EVP_Encrypt interface correctly. The correct pattern is one call to `EVP_EncryptInit`, then any number of calls to `EVP_EncryptUpdate` to encrypt additional data, and then one call to `EVP_EncryptFinal` to finalize the encryption process. You're missing the call to `EVP_EncryptFinal` or one of its variants.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk For AES/GCM encryption, there also needs to be a call to `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl()` to retrieve the AEAD authentication tag so the ciphertext can be authenticated on decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C code is executed, the following ciphertexts result for the three iterations:

```
i = 0: 0x7e81d12cb6cd69e538f709f69274f7f397c375b460cae4f6433b556bd0b0f839
i = 1: 0x97c4c7be1b67c61975fe97288599b1029984ba05633fefd942d98400d20829e1
i = 2: 0x861e3f9f54f44bce0d5afe3c9554bb503a7a675e398485693d00519111a152d9
```

These come about as follows:

- As the C code does not change the default IV length of 12 bytes, only the first 12 bytes of the 16 bytes IV are applied: `0x75717155363359522c22747d`.
- From this IV, the GCM algorithm determines an initial value consisting of the 12 bytes IV to which the 4 bytes `0x00000001` are appended: `0x75717155363359522c22747d00000001`. The initial value determined in this way is reserved for the later determination of the GCM authentication tag and is not used for the encryption itself.
  Please note that if the IV length is other than 12 bytes, a different algorithm is used to calculate the initial value (see below).
- For the encryption of the first plaintext block and all further plaintext blocks, the initial value is incremented with each block, i.e. for the first plaintext the counter has the value `0x75717155363359522c22747d00000002`.
- The first plaintext is two blocks in size, so the counter for the second plaintext has the value `0x75717155363359522c22747d00000004`.
- The second plaintext is also two blocks in size, so that the counter for the third plaintext has the value `0x75717155363359522c22747d00000006` and so on.

I am not aware of any EVP functions that retrieve the initial value or intermediate counter values. However, as both the calculation of the initial value and the incrementation are carried out automatically, there is actually no need for this (as already mentioned in the 1st comment).

Regarding encryption, GCM works like [CTR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#CTR), with the above counters corresponding to the IVs. The correctness of the counters can therefore be easily verified by encrypting with CTR and the determined counters instead of GCM and the 12 bytes IV.
The C code can be adapted accordingly (for the sake of simplicity without exception handling):

```c
void encrypt_with_CTR(unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* data)
{
    int cipherLength;
    unsigned char ciphertext[32];
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX* encrypt_ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(encrypt_ctx, EVP_aes_256_ctr(), NULL, key, iv);
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(encrypt_ctx, ciphertext, &cipherLength, data, 32);
    print_array((char*)"ciphertext: ", ciphertext, cipherLength);
}
...
unsigned char data[] = "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA";
unsigned char key[] = "\x3c\x57\x5e\x25\x5f\x43\x41\x69\x3d\x5e\x48\x29\x72\x54\x27\x55\x3e\x29\x28\x65\x31\x34\x4a\x3e\x52\x2f\x7c\x6a\x7b\x25\x78\x52";
unsigned char iv_1[] = "\x75\x71\x71\x55\x36\x33\x59\x52\x2c\x22\x74\x7d\x00\x00\x00\x02";
unsigned char iv_2[] = "\x75\x71\x71\x55\x36\x33\x59\x52\x2c\x22\x74\x7d\x00\x00\x00\x04";
unsigned char iv_3[] = "\x75\x71\x71\x55\x36\x33\x59\x52\x2c\x22\x74\x7d\x00\x00\x00\x06";
encrypt_with_CTR(key, iv_1, data); 
encrypt_with_CTR(key, iv_2, data); 
encrypt_with_CTR(key, iv_3, data);
```

Alternatively, this can be verified with CyberChef:

[`0x75717155363359522c22747d00000002`](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%273c575e255f4341693d5e4829725427553e29286531344a3e522f7c6a7b257852%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2775717155363359522c22747d00000002%27%7D,%27CTR%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=QUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUE):
`0x7e81d12cb6cd69e538f709f69274f7f397c375b460cae4f6433b556bd0b0f839`
[`0x75717155363359522c22747d00000004`](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%273c575e255f4341693d5e4829725427553e29286531344a3e522f7c6a7b257852%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2775717155363359522c22747d00000004%27%7D,%27CTR%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=QUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUE):
`0x97c4c7be1b67c61975fe97288599b1029984ba05633fefd942d98400d20829e1`
[`0x75717155363359522c22747d00000006`](https://gchq.github.io/CyberChef/#recipe=AES_Encrypt(%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%273c575e255f4341693d5e4829725427553e29286531344a3e522f7c6a7b257852%27%7D,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%2775717155363359522c22747d00000006%27%7D,%27CTR%27,%27Raw%27,%27Hex%27,%7B%27option%27:%27Hex%27,%27string%27:%27%27%7D)&input=QUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUFBQUE):
`0x861e3f9f54f44bce0d5afe3c9554bb503a7a675e398485693d00519111a152d9`

both of which, as expected, correspond to the ciphertexts of the GCM encryption with the 12 bytes IV.

---

Notes:

- The added value of GCM compared to CTR is authentication, which ensures the integrity of the data. GCM uses an authentication tag for this purpose. This tag is calculated by `EVP_EncryptFinal_ex()`, which is why this function must be called at the end of the encryption process (see first comment). The tag must then be retrieved using `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_GET_TAG, 16, tag)` (see second comment).
  Both calls are missing in the posted code, so that the tag is neither created nor retrieved. This is not a problem in this case, as the tag is not required for the demo program.
  With *regular* GCM encryption, however, both calls *must* be carried out!
- GCM is optimized for an IV length of 12 bytes, which is why the recommended IV size of 12 bytes should be used in practice for performance and compatibility reasons.
  If for some reason a different IV size must be used, `EVP_CIPHER_CTX_ctrl(ctx, EVP_CTRL_GCM_SET_IVLEN, iv_len, NULL)` can be used to specify a different length for the IV than the recommended 12 bytes. In this case, the initial value of the counter is determined differently, namely using the *GHASH* algorithm.
- [Here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) you can find the specification for GCM and especially GHASH and  [here](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Authenticated_Encryption_and_Decryption) an example for an *EVP Authenticated Encryption and Decryption* with GCM (with a 12 bytes IV or an IV of other length `iv_len`).

Comment: Thanks @Topaco, that was indeed helpful. One thing I was wondering is what happens to the counter in case of odd lengths like 37 bytes (37 % 16 != 0), when I call the function over 2 messages of lengths 37 each, how is the counter updated over each byte/block?

Comment: @prd-ld - The 2*37=74 bytes are encrypted as if they consisted of 4 complete blocks (with 16 bytes each) and a final incomplete block (with 10 bytes), i.e. 4*16+10=74 bytes. The counter of the first block has the value c ( = initial value + 1), of the second block c + 1, of the third block c + 2, of the fourth block c + 3 and of the fifth (incomplete) block c + 4.

Comment: That clarifies all things. Thanks @Topaco!